# Ubuntu Server 20.04 - Can't enable WiFi on Dell Latitude 5480

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration, dell-latitude, ubuntu-20.04

Hi Superuse community,

I'm reposting this question and solution here because it was deleted in Stack Overflow (I didn't know it was only software).

I'm having trouble connecting a Dell Latitude 5480 to WiFi running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

I followed linuxconfig.org's tutorial on how to enable the WiFi: https://linuxconfig.org/ubuntu-20-04-connect-to-wifi-from-command-line

When I did `ls /sys/class/net` I got the following output `enp0s31f6 lo wlp2s0`

I then edited the following file to configure the WiFi:

```
sudo nano /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml
```

To have the following contents:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    enp0s31f6:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: true
  version: 2
  wifis:
    wlp2s0:
      access-points:
        "network-name":
          password: "network-password"
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: true
```

I then ran the following command `sudo netplan apply` and no errors were displayed on the command line.

Finally, when I ran `ip a` I got the following output for `wlp2s0`:

```
3: wlp2s0: <No-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 20:16:b9:ea:2b:6c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:fff
```

I then tried to set the link up by running `sudo ip link set dev wlp2s0 up` and I got the same output when running `ip a`.

I made sure to check that the indentation was correct on the file and that the network's SSID name and password were correct.

When I ran `sudo lshw -class network` I got the following output for the WiFi card:

```
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 8265 / 8275
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 78
       serial: my serial number
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.4.0-generic firmware=36.77d01142.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:137 memory:ef200000-ef201fff
```

I can't get WiFi work but I can connect to the internet using the Ethernet cable.

Thank you in advanced!

**Update**:

When I reboot the machine it gets stuck configuring the network for 2 minutes.

When I run `sudo iw dev wlp2s0 scan` the network card lists the network's SSID.

After the reboot when I run `sudo netplan apply` I get the following output:

```
Warning: The unit file, source configuration file or drop-ins of netplan-wpa-wlp2s0.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.
Warning: The unit file, source configuration file or drop-ins of netplan-wpa-wlp2s0.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.
```

**Update 2**:

I looked on the systemctl process list and found that the `netplan-wpa-wlp2s0.service` failed.

When running `sudo systemctl status netplan-wpa-wlp2s0.service` I get the following output for the failed service:

```
● netplan-wpa-wlp2s0.service - WPA supplicant for netplan wlp2s0
     Loaded: loaded (/run/systemd/system/netplan-wpa-wlp2s0.service; enabled-runtime; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2020-08-18 18:12:07 UTC; 4min 50s ago
    Process: 616 ExecStart=/sbin/wpa_supplicant -c /run/netplan/wpa-wlp2s0.conf -iwlp2s0 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
   Main PID: 616 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Aug 18 18:12:07 scrubstation systemd[1]: Started WPA supplicant for netplan wlp2s0.
Aug 18 18:12:07 scrubstation systemd[616]: netplan-wpa-wlp2s0.service: Failed to execute command: No such file or directory
Aug 18 18:12:07 scrubstation systemd[616]: netplan-wpa-wlp2s0.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /sbin/wpa_supplicant: No such file or directory
Aug 18 18:12:07 scrubstation systemd[1]: netplan-wpa-wlp2s0.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Aug 18 18:12:07 scrubstation systemd[1]: netplan-wpa-wlp2s0.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

**Update 3**:

I tried running `sudo /sbin/wpa_supplicant -c /run/netplan/wpa-wlp2s0.conf -iwlp2s0` directly and got a bash error that the command was not found:

```
sudo: /sbin/wpa_supplicant: command not found
```

I checked `/run/netplan/wpa-wlp2s0.conf` and the file was properly configured.

I then installed the wpa_supplicant binary `sudo apt install wpasupplicant` and restarted the service `sudo systemctl status netplan-wpa-wlp2s0.service`

I then ran `ip a` and saw that the computer was connected to the WiFi!!

**Solution**:

1. Install the missing `wpa_supplicant` binary by running the following command:

```
sudo apt install wpasupplicant
```

2. Run the following command to identify the name of your wireless network
   interface:

   - I got the following output: `enp0s31f6 lo wlp2s0`

```
ls /sys/class/net
```

3. Edited the following file to configure the WiFi:

   - Note there should only be one file in `/etc/netplan/` edit the one
     that's there.

```
sudo nano /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml
```

4. Add the WiFi information to the file:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    enp0s31f6:
      optional: true
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: true
  version: 2
  wifis:
    wlp2s0:
      optional: true
      access-points:
        "network-name":
          password: "network-password"
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: true
```

5. Apply the changes to netplan by running the following command:

```
sudo netplan apply
```

Enjoy your WiFi!